# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Problem that at datagridview1 when I want string data from form1 with stafftextbox.text

```
Private Sub Edit_Booking_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.BookingTableAdapter2.Fill(Me.AdminDataSet7.Booking)
    Form1.StaffTextBox.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Selected

End Sub
```

Comment: Seems clear: no row was selected, so `SelectedRows(0)` is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

The DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0) itself is not a String that can be put into a Text property of a TextBox. You need to either address a cell within the SelectedRow, or, concatenate all the cell values from to row.
For example:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim s As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value.ToString

    ' OR

    Dim s2 As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("Country").Value.ToString

    ' OR

    Dim s3 As String = Nothing
    For Each c As DataGridViewCell In DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells
        s3 &= c.Value.ToString & " "
    Next

End Sub
```